# How to avoid unwanted pop up window using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When i try to open any page, In the middle or when the page is loading if any unwanted pop up window comes how can we avoid that pop up window and work further to load the page.

Comment: Will the popup come once or many times

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Comment: You've given us no info on if the popup is an alert or HTML-based, what the HTML of it is, or anything else. Please add detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Just add an explicit wait before executing this statement to avoid no such element exceptions

```
Alert alert = getDriver().switchTo().alert();
alert.dismiss();
```

Hope this helps you!!